# The tag [console-application] is irrelevant in a very large portion of the questions

Tags: discussion, tags

[console-application](/questions/tagged/console-application) is a relatively commonly used tag that very rarely serves a purpose. In my experience I have only seen this used when new programmers ask a question and it never has anything to do with the problem at hand (the same way they often add their IDE as a tag as well).

I would be surprised if more than 10% of the questions tagged as such actually have got anything to do with a console application in particular.

That being said: there are a few questions that specifically talk about the console, but as far as I can tell most of these can be just descriptive with the [console](/questions/tagged/console) tag.

Therefore I propose a cleanup for the former. I'm not entirely convinced a deletion is in order because some questions do seem to benefit from `console-application` rather than `console`, I'll leave that to the more advanced taggers to decide.

Frankly I'm not entirely sure what I'm supposed to do now. I've started with removing the `console-application` tag where it doesn't add any value to the question, feel free to join in. It has 2000 questions, after all.

Comment: I wonder what the [people who used both were thinking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console+console-application) As an aside these queries: [console](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/148466/how-are-tags-used-in-combination?TagName=console) and [console-application](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/148466/how-are-tags-used-in-combination?TagName=console-application) seem to back up your claims